# Having 'Appendix A' instead of 'A Appendix'

Tags: numbering, appendices, lncs

I would like to have my appendices labelled 'Appendix A', 'Appendix B', etc. However, when I use appendices in LaTeX (specifically `llncs` document class, downloadable at ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip), I instead get ''A Appendix', 'B Appendix' and so on. Is there any way to change that?

More specifically, this is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame]{llncs}

\begin{document}
\appendix
\section{Appendix: Foo Bar} %I want this to appear as 'Appendix A: Foo Bar'
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just as a note: not everyone will have `llncs` installed.  It would be better to make this a compilable example (using the `article` class, for example).  The solution that works for `article` will likely work for `llncs`.  **That said,** intentionally deviating from the style of a journal doesn't exactly make the publisher giggle with joy; the style exists for a reason.

Comment: I use ``llncs`` as a general format, but I understand what you mean. Changing my minimum working example to reflect this.

Comment: I my opinion, it is better to use a chapter as `appendix` and rename `\chaptername`. Then use sections as the several parts of appendix -- I also agree with Sean Allred's statement about `llncs`.

Comment: I withdraw my statement about `appendix` as `chapter` -- it is not necessary.

Comment: @SeanAllred You're wrong. `llncs` class is quite unique, so what works for `article` might not work for `llncs`.

Comment: @karlkoeller I can accept that. The leading answer below though proves the point, it would just be nice if OP at least linked to the files he was using.

Comment: @SeanAllred I agree. When the OP uses particular classes/packages and does not provide a link, it is always better to ask her/him for that.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution that uses only low-level LaTeX macros. (Copy the material starting with `\makeatletter` and ending with `\makeatother` to your document's preamble.) The example below employs the `llncs` document class, but works equally well with the `article` document class.

The trick, such as it is, consists of telling LaTeX to prefix the String "Appendix" to the section "number" *when in a section header* but not when cross-references to, say, "appendices A, B, and D" are needed.

If you want the appendix section header to read just "Appendix [some letter]" *without* a descriptive string, you can do so by typing `\section{}` or `\section{\null}` -- after having executed `\appendix`, naturally.

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\makeatletter
%% The "\@seccntformat" command is an auxiliary command
%% (see pp. 26f. of 'The LaTeX Companion,' 2nd. ed.)
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}  % default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% enable individual control
}
\let\oldappendix\appendix %% save current definition of \appendix
\renewcommand\appendix{%
    \oldappendix
    \newcommand{\section@cntformat}{\appendixname~\thesection\quad}
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{cleveref} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\section{Hello}

As we will show in \cref{app:a,app:b,app:d}, \dots

\appendix %% appendices 
\section{Postfix 1} \label{app:a}
\section{Postfix 2} \label{app:b}
\section{Postfix 3} \label{app:c}
\section{Postfix 4} \label{app:d}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A follow-up comment: This answer employs the the `llncs` document class, because that's what the OP was using. This answer works just as well with other document classes, notably the `article` class.

Answer (score 4):

I am actually not answering this question but the question [Show Appendix Number/Counter After Appendix Title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/545153/118714) which was closed due to similarity with this question while I was about to submit my answer.

The closed question is about `article.cls`.
This question is about `llncs.cls` which seems to be based on `article.cls`.

So my answer to the closed question probably is useful for this question, too.

If it is not, blame the vote-for-closing-fetishists. ;-)

---

With sectioning-commands (no matter whether they appear in the frontmatter or in the mainmatter or in the backmatter/appendix) you usually provide a title. In case you wish to provide titles with sections that occur in the appendix, I can offer this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% \let\savedcontentsline=\contentsline
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, colorlinks]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{headings}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{texorpdfstring}{\let\texorpdfstring\@firstoftwo}{}
\@ifundefined{hyper@makecurrent}{}{%
  \usepackage{xpatch}%
  \newcommand*\Hy@subsectionstring{subsection}%
  \newcommand*\Hy@subsubsectionstring{subsubsection}%
  \newcommand*\Hy@subsecapp{subsection}%
  \newcommand*\Hy@subsubsecapp{subsubsection}%
  \xpatchcmd{\hyper@makecurrent}{%
    \ifx\Hy@param\Hy@chapterstring\let\Hy@param\Hy@chapapp\fi
  }{%
    \ifx\Hy@param\Hy@chapterstring\let\Hy@param\Hy@chapapp\fi
    \ifx\Hy@param\Hy@subsectionstring\let\Hy@param\Hy@subsecapp\fi
    \ifx\Hy@param\Hy@subsubsectionstring\let\Hy@param\Hy@subsubsecapp\fi
%    \show\Hy@param
  }{%
    \@latex@info{Command \string\hyper@makecurrent patched successfully}%
    \message{Command \string\hyper@makecurrent patched successfully\on@line}%
  }{%
    \@latex@error{Command \string\hyper@makecurrent not patched successfully}%
                 {You're in trouble here.}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\labelfork[2]{%
  \ifx\thepage\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{#1}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\appendix@l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum\c@tocdepth >\z@ 
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{\appendixtocwidth}%
    \begingroup
    \parindent\z@
    \rightskip\@pnumwidth
    \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
    \leavevmode
    \bfseries
    \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
    \hskip-\leftskip
    #1%
    \nobreak\hfil
    \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss#2\kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi 
}%
\newcommand\appendix@l@subsection{%
 %\@dottedtocline {2}{1.5em}{2.3em}
 \@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{\dimexpr0.8em+\appendixtocwidth\relax}%
}%
\newcommand\appendix@l@subsubsection{%
 %\@dottedtocline {3}{3.8em}{3.2em}
 \@dottedtocline{3}{3.8em}{\dimexpr1.7em+\appendixtocwidth\relax}%
}%
\newcommand\appendixlatsections{%
  \let\l@section=\appendix@l@section
  \let\l@subsection=\appendix@l@subsection
  \let\l@subsubsection=\appendix@l@subsubsection
}%
\newcommand\doappendixstuff{%
  \renewcommand\thesection{%
    \texorpdfstring{\noexpand\labelfork{}{\appendixname\protect~}}{\appendixname\space}%
    \@Alph\c@section
    \texorpdfstring{\noexpand\labelfork{}{:}}{:}%
  }%
  \renewcommand\thesubsection{%
    \texorpdfstring{\noexpand\labelfork{}{\appendixname\protect~}}{\appendixname\space}%
    \@Alph\c@section.\number\value{subsection}%
    \texorpdfstring{\noexpand\labelfork{}{:}}{:}%
  }%
  \renewcommand\thesubsubsection{%
    \texorpdfstring{\noexpand\labelfork{}{\appendixname\protect~}}{\appendixname\space}%
    \@Alph\c@section.\number\value{subsection}.\number\value{subsubsection}%
    \texorpdfstring{\noexpand\labelfork{}{:}}{:}%
  }%
  \let\Hy@subsecapp\Hy@appendixstring
  \let\Hy@subsubsecapp\Hy@appendixstring
  \begingroup
  \bfseries
  \settowidth\@tempdima{\appendixname~A:~}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\def\string\appendixtocwidth{\the\@tempdima}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\appendixlatsections}%
  \endgroup
  % \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\savedcontentsline{section}{{\large Appendices}}{}\protected@file@percent}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Intro's subsection}
\subsubsection{Intro's subsubsection}

I would like to reference the appendix with A,B,C as this Appendix: \ref{ap:a}, but in the appendix in the finish of the page I want the letter A after the word Appendix just one time.

\subsection{Referencing}

\noindent\verb|\ref{ap:a}|: \ref{ap:a}

\noindent\verb|\ref{ap:a.1}|: \ref{ap:a.1}

\noindent\verb|\ref{ap:a.1.1}|: \ref{ap:a.1.1}

\noindent\verb|\ref{ap:b}|: \ref{ap:b}

\noindent\verb|\ref{ap:c}|: \ref{ap:c}

\noindent\verb|\nameref{ap:a}|: \nameref{ap:a}

\noindent\verb|\nameref{ap:a.1}|: \nameref{ap:a.1}

\noindent\verb|\nameref{ap:a.1.1}|: \nameref{ap:a.1.1}

\noindent\verb|\nameref{ap:b}|: \nameref{ap:b}

\noindent\verb|\nameref{ap:c}|: \nameref{ap:c}

\noindent\verb|\autoref{ap:a}|: \autoref{ap:a}

\noindent\verb|\autoref{ap:a.1}|: \autoref{ap:a.1}

\noindent\verb|\autoref{ap:a.1.1}|: \autoref{ap:a.1.1}

\noindent\verb|\autoref{ap:b}|: \autoref{ap:b}

\noindent\verb|\autoref{ap:c}|: \autoref{ap:c}

\noindent\verb|\hyperref[ap:a]{\autoref*{ap:a}: \nameref*{ap:a}}|:\\ \hyperref[ap:a]{\autoref*{ap:a}: \nameref*{ap:a}}

\noindent\verb|\hyperref[ap:a.1]{\autoref*{ap:a.1}: \nameref*{ap:a.1}}|:\\ \hyperref[ap:a.1]{\autoref*{ap:a.1}: \nameref*{ap:a.1}}

\noindent\verb|\hyperref[ap:a.1.1]{\autoref*{ap:a.1.1}: \nameref*{ap:a.1.1}}|:\\ \hyperref[ap:a.1.1]{\autoref*{ap:a.1.1}: \nameref*{ap:a.1.1}}

\noindent\verb|\hyperref[ap:b]{\autoref*{ap:b}: \nameref*{ap:b}}|:\\ \hyperref[ap:b]{\autoref*{ap:b}: \nameref*{ap:b}}

\noindent\verb|\hyperref[ap:c]{\autoref*{ap:c}: \nameref*{ap:c}}|:\\ \hyperref[ap:c]{\autoref*{ap:c}: \nameref*{ap:c}}

\newpage

\appendix
\doappendixstuff

\section{First appendix}
\label{ap:a}

\subsection{First appendix's first sub-appendix}
\label{ap:a.1}

\subsubsection{First appendix's first sub-appendix's first subsub-appendix}
\label{ap:a.1.1}

\subsection{First appendix's second sub-appendix}

\section{Second appendix}
\label{ap:b}

\section{Third appendix}
\label{ap:c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

In case you wish not to provide titles with sections that occur in the appendix, I can offer this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% \let\savedcontentsline=\contentsline
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered, colorlinks]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{headings}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{texorpdfstring}{\let\texorpdfstring\@firstoftwo}{}
\@ifundefined{hyper@makecurrent}{}{%
  \usepackage{xpatch}%
  \newcommand*\Hy@subsectionstring{subsection}%
  \newcommand*\Hy@subsubsectionstring{subsubsection}%
  \newcommand*\Hy@subsecapp{subsection}%
  \newcommand*\Hy@subsubsecapp{subsubsection}%
  \xpatchcmd{\hyper@makecurrent}{%
    \ifx\Hy@param\Hy@chapterstring\let\Hy@param\Hy@chapapp\fi
  }{%
    \ifx\Hy@param\Hy@chapterstring\let\Hy@param\Hy@chapapp\fi
    \ifx\Hy@param\Hy@subsectionstring\let\Hy@param\Hy@subsecapp\fi
    \ifx\Hy@param\Hy@subsubsectionstring\let\Hy@param\Hy@subsubsecapp\fi
%    \show\Hy@param
  }{%
    \@latex@info{Command \string\hyper@makecurrent patched successfully}%
    \message{Command \string\hyper@makecurrent patched successfully\on@line}%
  }{%
    \@latex@error{Command \string\hyper@makecurrent not patched successfully}%
                 {You're in trouble here.}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\labelfork[2]{%
  \ifx\thepage\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{#1}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand\appendix@l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum\c@tocdepth >\z@ 
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{\appendixtocwidth}%
    \begingroup
    \parindent\z@
    \rightskip\@pnumwidth
    \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
    \leavevmode
    \bfseries
    \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
    \hskip-\leftskip
    #1%
    \nobreak\hfil
    \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss#2\kern-\p@\kern\p@}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi 
}%
\newcommand\appendix@l@subsection{%
 %\@dottedtocline {2}{1.5em}{2.3em}
 \@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{\dimexpr0.8em+\appendixtocwidth\relax}%
}%
\newcommand\appendix@l@subsubsection{%
 %\@dottedtocline {3}{3.8em}{3.2em}
 \@dottedtocline{3}{3.8em}{\dimexpr1.7em+\appendixtocwidth\relax}%
}%
\newcommand\appendixlatsections{%
  \let\l@section=\appendix@l@section
  \let\l@subsection=\appendix@l@subsection
  \let\l@subsubsection=\appendix@l@subsubsection
}%
\newcommand\doappendixstuff{%
  \renewcommand\thesection{%
    \texorpdfstring{\noexpand\labelfork{}{\appendixname\protect~}}{\appendixname\space}%
    \@Alph\c@section
  }%
  \renewcommand\thesubsection{%
    \texorpdfstring{\noexpand\labelfork{}{\appendixname\protect~}}{\appendixname\space}%
    \@Alph\c@section.\number\value{subsection}%
  }%
  \renewcommand\thesubsubsection{%
    \texorpdfstring{\noexpand\labelfork{}{\appendixname\protect~}}{\appendixname\space}%
    \@Alph\c@section.\number\value{subsection}.\number\value{subsubsection}%
  }%
  \newcommand\savedsection{}%
  \newcommand\savedsubsection{}%
  \newcommand\savedsubsubsection{}%
  \let\savedsection=\section
  \let\savedsubsection=\subsection
  \let\savedsubsubsection=\subsubsection
  \renewcommand*\section{\savedsection{}\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{\thesection}}%
  \renewcommand*\subsection{\savedsubsection{}\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{\thesubsection}}%
  \renewcommand*\subsubsection{\savedsubsubsection{}\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{\thesubsubsection}}%
  \let\Hy@subsecapp\Hy@appendixstring
  \let\Hy@subsubsecapp\Hy@appendixstring
  \begingroup
  \bfseries
  \settowidth\@tempdima{\appendixname~A}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\def\string\appendixtocwidth{\the\@tempdima}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\string\appendixlatsections}%
  \endgroup
  % \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\savedcontentsline{section}{{\large Appendices}}{}\protected@file@percent}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Intro's subsection}
\subsubsection{Intro's subsubsection}

I would like to reference the appendix with A,B,C as this Appendix: \ref{ap:a}, but in the appendix in the finish of the page I want the letter A after the word Appendix just one time.

\subsection{Referencing}

\noindent\verb|\ref{ap:a}|: \ref{ap:a}

\noindent\verb|\ref{ap:a.1}|: \ref{ap:a.1}

\noindent\verb|\ref{ap:a.1.1}|: \ref{ap:a.1.1}

\noindent\verb|\ref{ap:b}|: \ref{ap:b}

\noindent\verb|\ref{ap:c}|: \ref{ap:c}

\noindent\verb|\nameref{ap:a}|: \nameref{ap:a}

\noindent\verb|\nameref{ap:a.1}|: \nameref{ap:a.1}

\noindent\verb|\nameref{ap:a.1.1}|: \nameref{ap:a.1.1}

\noindent\verb|\nameref{ap:b}|: \nameref{ap:b}

\noindent\verb|\nameref{ap:c}|: \nameref{ap:c}

\noindent\verb|\autoref{ap:a}|: \autoref{ap:a}

\noindent\verb|\autoref{ap:a.1}|: \autoref{ap:a.1}

\noindent\verb|\autoref{ap:a.1.1}|: \autoref{ap:a.1.1}

\noindent\verb|\autoref{ap:b}|: \autoref{ap:b}

\noindent\verb|\autoref{ap:c}|: \autoref{ap:c}

\newpage

\appendix
\doappendixstuff

\section
\label{ap:a}

\subsection
\label{ap:a.1}

\subsubsection
\label{ap:a.1.1}

\subsection

\section
\label{ap:b}

\section
\label{ap:c}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]