# How should equations in the appendix to be numbered, if the section they are in is unnumbered?

Tags: numbering, appendices, elsarticle

I am using the `elsarticle` document class. As I have only one appendix, I would like to remove the letter "A" after "Appendix". Unfortunately, if I write `\section*{Appendix title}`, the numbering of equations disappears.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

bla bla bla

\appendix 
\section*{Appendix title}

\begin{equation}
 3+3 = 6
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not use LaTeX macros to shortcut the beginning and ending of an equation. It is very bad style.

Comment: How re equations in the appendix to be numbered, if the section they are in is unnumbered?

Comment: @Johannes_B I took the liberty to follow your suggestion.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Which one?

Comment: @Johannes_B I changed the title of the question.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you want the equations in the appendix to be numbered as `A.1`, `A.2`, etc. If that's the case, I would suggest you remove the `\appendix` instruction and insert the following ones in its place:

```
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand\theequation{A.\arabic{equation}}
```

followed by `\section*{Appendix Title}`.

---

*Addendum*: The `elsarticle` document class modifies LaTeX's `\appendix` macro in a faulty way. Specifically, its modification of the `\appendix` macro contains the following instruction:

```
\gdef\thesection{\appendixname\@Alph\c@section}%
```

This leaves no space between the word "Appendix" and the section counter ("A", "B", etc). The correct instruction would be

```
\gdef\thesection{\appendixname\ \@Alph\c@section}%
```

Worse still, the approach taken by the `elsarticle` document class -- viz., including `\appendixname` inside `\thesection` -- runs into serious trouble if one wishes to use `\autoref` (from the `hyperref` package) or `\cref` (from the `cleveref` package) to create cross-references to numbered sections in the appendix portion of the document. To get around this problem see, e.g., the answer given to the posting [Having 'Appendix A' instead of 'A Appendix'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160839/5001).
Adapting these ideas to the `elsarticle` document class, it seems like a good idea to add the following code to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname.\hskip0.5em}    % default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% enable individual control
}
\patchcmd{\appendix}{\appendixname}{}{}{}
\appto{\appendix}{%
    \newcommand{\section@cntformat}{\appendixname\ \thesection.\hskip0.5em}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: @NaT - Feel free to "accept" the answer -- by clicking on the checkmark symbol -- if it has fully solved the issue(s) at hand. ;-)