# Modifying subsection headings in appendix, elsarticle document class

Tags: elsarticle, appendix

Could anyone tell me how to modify the headings in Appendix of an article? I need to suppress the word 'Appendix' in the subsection headings to *A.1. Subheading-1*,  *A.2. Subheading-2* and so on (please see the attached screenshot).

[image: screenshot of output]

I'm using the following commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}
Main text
\appendix
\section{Main Heading - 1} 
\subsection{Subheading-1}
\subsection{Subheading-2}

\section{Main Heading - 2} 
\subsection{Subheading-1}
\subsection{Subheading-2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300438/5001) to the question [How should equations in the appendix to be numbered, if the section they are in is unnumbered?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300435/5001) notes that "the elsarticle document class modifies LaTeX's `\appendix` macro in a faulty way". [Shameless self-citation alert!] Applying the methods used in the cited answer, I suggest you modify the `\appendix` macro by running the following code in the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% the next 4 lines are straight from "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname.\hskip0.5em}    % default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% enable individual control
}
\appto{\appendix}{%
    \renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
    \newcommand{\section@cntformat}{\appendixname~\Alph{section}.\hskip0.5em}
    \newcommand{\subsection@cntformat}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\hskip0.5em}}
\makeatother
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

[image]

```
documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname.\hskip0.5em}    % default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}% enable individual control
}
\appto{\appendix}{%
    \renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
    \newcommand{\section@cntformat}{\appendixname~\Alph{section}.\hskip0.5em}
    \newcommand{\subsection@cntformat}{\Alph{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\hskip0.5em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Bla}
\subsection{Ble}
\subsection{Bli}

\appendix

\section{Main Heading - 1} 
\subsection{Subheading-1}
\subsection{Subheading-2}

\section{Main Heading - 2} 
\subsection{Subheading-1}
\subsection{Subheading-2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was super helpful.

Comment: @Ana - You're most welcome!