# How can I remove the initial letter in the Appendix heading?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, appendix

I am writing a paper for school in which I need to include appendices. Currently, I am using the `\appendix` command at the end of the document (just before `\end{document}`) to insert these appendices. When creating a new appendix, I used the `\section` command, and it's working just fine, and it does what I want. Except, there is one problem. The heading shows in the following way:

**A Appendix A**

I am trying to get rid of the first A in the heading. These are the packages and commands I am using in my document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink, noabbrev]{cleveref}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!100!black}
    }

\begin{document}


    We can see in \Cref{app:A} the original text in blah, blah, blah.  
    \Cref{app:B} depicts a table with the results from this study.  
    Finally, \Cref{app:C} shows a plot of these results...

    \appendix
    \section{Appendix A}\label{app:A}

    Text here...

    \section{Appendix B}\label{app:B}

    Table here...

    \section{Appendix C}\label{app:C}

    Figure here...

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

I know that if I use the command `\section*{Appendix A}` as opposed to `\section{Appendix A}` then the first letter goes away. The problem with that solution is that I can't use the [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref?lang=en) to cross-reference this item in the body of my text. And if I do reference it using `\Cref{app:A}`, it simply links to the previous section that was not starred. In my case, the hyperlink is connected to my conclusion and not my appendices. I need to be able to reference the appendices in my text, and I need to get rid of the first letter because it violates APA formatting rules, which is the formatting used in my field.

I hope someone can help me with this. Also, I'm new to LaTeX, so I'd prefer simple solutions (such as a `\renew` command) that won't require that I change my entire document because my paper is basically done. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you seen the posting [Having 'Appendix A' instead of 'A Appendix'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160839/5001)? The solution provided in the [associated answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160850/5001) works just fine with the macros of the `cleveref` package. The only downside is that you'll have to come up with more imaginative sectioning header names than "Appendix A", "Appendix B", etc.

Comment: @Mico Unfortunately that solution didn't work for me. Adding the code to my preamble, as specified, made no difference in my output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reformat the titles of the appendices with `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink, noabbrev]{cleveref}  
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!100!black}
    }

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

    We can see in \Cref{app:A} the original text in blah, blah, blah.  
    \Cref{app:B} depicts a table with the results from this study.  
    Finally, \Cref{app:C} shows a plot of these results...

    \appendix
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries}{\appendixname~\thesection}{1em}{}

    \section{}\label{app:A}

    Text here...


    \section{}\label{app:B}

    Table here...

    \section{}\label{app:C}

    Figure here...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly. An additional note for those using APA and not well-versed on LaTeX, adding `\centering` after `\bfseries` will center the heading.

Comment: @Ernesto May I suggest to use `\filcenter` instead of `\centering`: `\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\appendixname~\thesection}{1em}{}` in that case?

Comment: I was not familiar with that command. Is `\filcenter` typically used for sections and the like, while `\centering` is used for the body of the text?

Comment: @Ernesto It can be found in the titlesec manual and is suggested there, probably for good reasons.