# Show Appendix Number/Counter After Appendix Title

Tags: appendices

I would like to reference appendices with "A,B,C,...", as in "Appendix A", but in the appendix at the end of the document I want the letter "A" *after* the word "Appendix", as in "Appendix A".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Reference to appendix \ref{ap:a}. 

\appendix
\section{Appendix}
\label{ap:a}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Kindly provide the type of documentclass (.cls) that you have used for compiling your MWE. Documentclass files (.cls) such as article, report, book, etc. Your requirement is not clear.

Comment: If you do not believe this to be a duplicate of that question, please let us know by editing the question to make it your intent clearer.

Comment: As the vote-for-close-fetishists have struck again, [I posted an answer to the linked question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545208/118714)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you use report class and use \chapter{}.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

Reference to appendix \ref{ap:a}. 

\appendix
\chapter{}
\label{ap:a}

\chapter{}
\label{ap:b}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly for me; `\ref{ap:a}` yields "Appendix 1". Additionally, having to number/label the appendices manually (i.e. having to write the letters "A", "B", etc. yourself) and not having them appear if one calls `\tableofcontents` are, potentially, inconveniences.

Comment: @steve what documentclass are you using for this?

Comment: `article` (I just copy pasted your MWE).

Answer (score 0):

You will get what you want automatically if you use the `report` class or the `book` instead of `article`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

I would like to reference the appendix with A,B,C as this Appendix \ref{ap:a}, but in the appendix in the finish of the page I want the letter A after the word Appendix just one time.

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix A}
\label{ap:a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think when \chapter{Appendix A} replaced with \chapter{}, i.e., no input name, it works perfectly fine, otherwise it reproduces the text "Appendix A" twice.