# Use appendix letter in figure and table captions

Tags: tables, floats, appendix

I have multiple appendices and use the `appendix` package to name them

```
Appendix A    Some Title
Appendix B    Different Title
```

Now these appendices contain tables and figures and I would like to refer to them by their appendix letter. That is, in Appendix A, they should be called `Figure A1` or `Figure A2`, whereas in Appendix B, this should be `Figure B1`and so forth.

I could declare at the beginning of each appendix,

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{A\arabic{figure}} 
\renewcommand\thetable{A\arabic{table}}
```

and vary the `A\arabic{...}` part but I wondered whether there is a variable holding the appendix letter. Assuming this variable is called `\appxletter`, I could then declare once

```
\renewcommand\thefigure{\appxletter\arabic{figure}} 
\renewcommand\thetable{\appxletter\arabic{table}}
```

and only reset the counters for each appendix (unless this can also be automated?). Is there something that makes this possible?

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Make it an answer? I use the article class.

Comment: Off-topic: If you want the appendix sectioning headers to say "Appendix A <Some material>", "Appendix B <Some more material>", etc rather than just "A <Some material>", "B <Some more material>", etc, do take a look at the posting [Having 'Appendix A' instead of 'A Appendix'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160839/5001). That query employs the `llncs` document class; however, the suggested solutions work with the `article` class as well.

Comment: Thanks! I use ```\usepackage[title]{appendix}```, which accomplishes the same goal, I believe.

Comment: You are correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you employ the `article` document class along with the [appendix](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendix) package, the following instructions -- to be placed after the `\appendix` instruction -- will let you achieve your formatting objectives for the caption numbers of `figure` and `table` environments placed in one of the document's appendices:

```
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection\arabic{table}}
```

The first two instructions tell LaTeX to reset the `figure` and `table` counters to zero each time a `\section` directive is encountered within the appendix. The final two instructions determine how the caption numbers are displayed, *viz.*, by prefixing the section letters (`A`, `B`, etc) to the `table` and `figure` arabic numerals.